# Minimal or Minimum - Which word should I use here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, modifiers

The sentence is,
What are the “minimal/minimum" needs of your life?

Which word would be grammatically right and overall appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common confusion.

*Minimum* refers to "the least amount" whereas *minimal* means "a very little/small amount, often negligible."

Look at this difference:

> The minimum contribution for this fund-raising is USD 10. 
>   Jack contributed minimal amount. I certainly expected more as he's a businessperson.

Note that the minimal amount is your *mind-set* as you expected some great contribution. Even if Jack has contributed USD 1000, you had expected at least USD 5000 as he's a big businessperson. On the other hand *minimum* amount is the least maount (below that is not accepted).

In this sense, both the sentences are okay but to me, *what are the minimum needs of your life* sounds natural as we are talking about the *least needs* and not binding someone with a very negligible amount of something.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that "minimum" is both a noun and an adjective, whereas "minimal" is an adjective only.